# UnsatisfiedDependencyException , BeanCreationException..in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am at the beginner level in Spring , was trying to learn spring by building a basic application , in which data will be stored in dynamo DB and for which I am using Java SDK for dynamo DB, I am including all the files and error here

**Main Application**

```
package main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages =  {"main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring"})
public class SpringPracticeApplication {
    public static void main(String []args){
        SpringApplication.run(SpringPracticeApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
    package main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.controllers;

import main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.dto.IssueDTO;
import main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.module.IssueAssignment;
import main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.repository.IssueRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Issue")
public class gdaycontroller {

    @Autowired
    private IssueRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/gday")
    public String gdayf(){
        return "G’day World";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void CreateIssue(@RequestBody IssueAssignment issue) {
        repository.insert(issue);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<IssueAssignment> getOneIssueDetailsOf(@RequestParam String IssueId, @RequestParam String IssueName) {
        IssueAssignment issue=repository.getOneIssue(IssueId,IssueName);
        return new ResponseEntity<IssueAssignment>(issue,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void updateIssueAssigne(@RequestBody String IssueId,@RequestBody String AssigneName,@RequestBody String IssueName) {
        repository.updateIssueAssigne(IssueId,AssigneName,IssueName);
    }


}
```

**Repository Class**

```
package main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.repository;


import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.module.IssueAssignment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class IssueRepository {


    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBMapper mapper;

    public void insert(IssueAssignment issue) {
        mapper.save(issue);
    }

    public IssueAssignment getOneIssue(String IssueId,String IssueName) {
        return mapper.load(IssueAssignment.class,IssueId,IssueName);
    }

    public void updateIssueAssigne(String IssueID,String AssigneName,String IssueName) {
            IssueAssignment issue = getOneIssue(IssueID, IssueName);
            issue.setAssigneName(AssigneName);
            mapper.save(issue);
    }
}
```

**Model Class for Dynamo DB**

```
package main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.module;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "IssueAssignment")
public class IssueAssignment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String IssueId;
    private String IssueName;
    private Boolean AssigneStatus;
    private String AssigneName;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "IssueId")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getIssueId() {
        return IssueId;
    }

    public void setIssueId(String IssueId) {
        this.IssueId=IssueId;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getIssueName() {
        return IssueName;
    }

    public void setIssueName(String issueName) {
        this.IssueName = issueName;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    public  String getAssigneName() {
        return AssigneName;
    }

    public void setAssigneName(String assigneName) {
        AssigneName = assigneName;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public Boolean getAssigneStatus() {
        return AssigneStatus;
    }

    public void setAssigneStatus(Boolean assigneStatus) {
        this.AssigneStatus=assigneStatus;
    }
}
```

**DynamoDbConfig class for setting up Dynamo DB**

```
package main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.dynamodbconfig;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class dynamoDbconfig {

    @Value("${amazon.access.key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.access.secret-key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Value("${amazon.region}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Value("${amazon.end-point.url}")
    private String awsDynamoDBEndPoint;

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper mapper(){
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBConfig());
    }

    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDBConfig(){
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey,awsSecretKey)))
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
 amazon:
  access:
    key:AKIAQQABW4A
    secret-key:AKIABWCF6E24A
  region:
  end-point:
    url: dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

server:
  port:9001
```

I tried with component Scan , I paid the attention to include the class within same base package  but still the below error is not going

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gdaycontroller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'issueRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDbconfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'amazon.access.key' in value "${amazon.access.key}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at main.java.com.ankur.practice.spring.SpringPracticeApplication.main(SpringPracticeApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'issueRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDbconfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'amazon.access.key' in value "${amazon.access.key}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDbconfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'amazon.access.key' in value "${amazon.access.key}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'amazon.access.key' in value "${amazon.access.key}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:936) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you share your configs?

Comment: Hi I have shared

Comment: As already mentioned by @ray, validate your yml file to make sure formatting is correct. There are many online yml validator tools e.g. https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a space after `colon (:)` in your `application.yml`.

**Make sure format of your** `yml` **is correct**.

Example: `key: AKIAQQABW4A`

```
amazon:
  access:
    key: AKIAQQABW4A
    secret-key: AKIABWCF6E24A
  region:
  end-point:
    url: dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

server:
  port: 9001
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
> 'amazon.access.key' in value "${amazon.access.key}"

Check if `amazon.access.key` is present in configuration.

Comment: Hi all aws config is defined in application.properties file which is under src/main/resources